# curl -F for uploading not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

Hi I am trying to upload a file to a web server but curl does not seem to be working properly in Ubuntu, because I've been using the same code for my windows 8 based computer and I have not encountered any problem. When I tried my code both in firefox and google chrome but same result this is the error i am getting:

**EDITED: 
I FINALLY GOT IT WORKING!! Turns out the problem was in my file permission..
and here is my code(**EDITED**):

```
    <?php
$id = array(
    "0" => "62",

);

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){
    print_r($id[$x]);

//check account
$xml_str="<request type='UPLOAD_CONTENT' username='user' password='".md5('pass')."' identification=''>
<content contenttype='NORMAL' caption='sunny test' md5='".md5_file('sunnys.package')."' terminalidlist='".$id[$x]."' downloaddatetype='ANYDATE' downloadtimetype='ANYTIME'/>
</request>";
$url = "http://localhost:8080/CommitLoginAction.do" . urlencode($xml_str);
$response = `curl -F file=@sunnys.package $url`;
echo($url);
$data = simplexml_load_string($response);

print_r($response);
}
?>
```

Again, I've already debug this and I'm only having problems with curl. and I've already checked curl is already installed and enabled in my server. If anyone of you could help me, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!!

Comment: That error message doesn’t seem to be directly connected to cURL, but rather just a warning issued by the browser because it does not receive any indication about the character encoding of the response. // Have you tried using PHP’s cURL extension instead of trying to invoke cURL via backtick operators?

Comment: I edited my code, I actually have no idea how to execute your suggestion but I tried searching the net and this is what I found. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Oh and I tried removing the backtick first before changing my codes but still no luck. :\

Comment: I think I found the problem, I tried running the curl in terminal and when I did, it says that the file could not open file.. I'm still searching what causes this problem since it doesn't have any problem when I use it on a different server.